# How to access value of value in AWS Step Function condition?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I need my StateMachine to evaluate a value of a value from the output of a Lambda Function. I am not able to access the value since it is nested within the JSON object. I am not able to find the right StateMachine syntax to capture the right values.

State Machine:

```
{
  "StartAt": "Pass_1",
  "States": {
    "take_db_snapshot": {
      "Type":"Task",
      "Resource":"arn:aws:lambda:XXXXXXXXXX:function:se-db-reload",
      "Next":"Pass_2"
    },
    "Pass_2": {
      "Comment": "Pass for logging and debugging. No Action.",
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Next": "snapshot_waiter"
    },
    "snapshot_waiter": {
      "Type":"Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "And": [
            {
              "Variable":"$$.event.db-reload-step",
              "StringEquals": "create_instance"
            },
            {
              "Variable":"$$.event.status-code",
              "NumericEquals":200
            }
          ],
          "Next":"Pass_3"
        },
        {
          "Variable":"$$.event.status-code",
          "NumericEquals":408,
          "Next":"snapshot_waiter"
        },
        {
          "Variable":"$$.event.status-code",
          "Comment":"Snapshot creation Error, try again",
          "NumericEquals":400,
          "Next":"take_db_snapshot"
        }
      ]
    }
.
.
.
```

This is the output from `Pass_2`, or the Input into the `snapshot_waiter` State.

```
{
  "name": "Pass_2",
  "input": {
    "event": {
      "db-reload-step": "take_snapshot_waiter",
      "status-code": 200,
      }
    }
  },
  "inputDetails": {
    "truncated": false
  }
}
```

Comment: In your Lambda function that recieves the JSON data -- create application logic to parse the JSON to get the value you want. Every Step in a workflow is a Lambda function that contains your logic.